# Basic Objective C Syntax Question

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios

Can someone confirm my suspicion on this line of code.

```
NSUInteger newPath[] = {[indexPath section],0};
```

I'm pretty sure it's a C array of NSUIntegers.
Am I right about this?
Can you even make C arrays of Objective C objects?

Here is the code in context:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *) tableViewEditingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

if ([self isToManyRelationshipSection:[indexPath section]]) {
    NSUInteger newPath[] = {[indexPath section],0};
    NSIndexPath *row0IndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:newPath length:2];

    NSString *rowKey = [rowKeys nestedObjectAtIndexPath:row0IndexPath];
    NSString *rowLabel = [rowLabels nestedObjectAtIndexPath:row0IndexPath];
    NSMutableSet *rowSet = [managedObject mutableSetValueForKey:rowKey];//!!!: to-many?
    NSArray *rowArray = [NSArray arrayByOrderingSet:rowSet byKey:rowLabel ascending:YES];

    if ([indexPath row] >= [rowArray count]) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    }

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
```

Comment: NSUInteger isnt an object, its a c type, defined here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW71

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize. So it's a dynamic basic type. "When building 32-bit applications, NSUInteger is a 32-bit unsigned integer. A 64-bit application treats NSUInteger as a 64-bit unsigned integer"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're correct.  However...

```
NSUInteger newPath[] = {[indexPath section],0};
NSIndexPath *row0IndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:newPath length:2];
```

I would **strongly** discourage you from using this format to create an `NSIndexPath` that's intended for use in a `UITableView`.  [There's a convenience method to do this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007175-CH3-SW1) *much* more simply:

```
NSIndexPath *row0IndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:[indexPath section]];
```

Answer (score 3):

> I'm pretty sure it's a C array of NSUIntegers. Am I right about this?

Yep, it sure is.

> Can you even make C arrays of Objective C objects?

You can. For example, this is an array of two `NSString *`:

```
NSString *myStrings[] = {@"one", @"two"};
```

Is this useful? Sometimes, but it's almost always beneficial to use an `NSArray` if you need an array of objects.

Comment: @MakingScienceFictionFact If its such a great answer, then I suggest you click the Check next to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

NSUInteger is not an Objective-c object. It is a typedef for an unsigned integer. Depending on your platform, it may be int or long. But it isn't an object. So you just have a c array of ints, basically.